# Can someone tell me why this is not a constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I am attempting to write a linked list of pointer-to-member-functions using constexpr. Mostly for fun but it may have a useful application.

```
struct Foo;

using MethodPtr = void (Foo::*)();

struct Node
{
    constexpr Node(MethodPtr method, const Node* next)
        : Method(method)
        , Next(next)
    {}

    constexpr Node Push(MethodPtr method)
    {
        return Node(method, this);
    }

    MethodPtr Method;
    const Node* Next;
};

struct Foo
{
    constexpr static Node GetMethods()
    {
        return Node{&Foo::Method1, nullptr}
            .Push(&Foo::Method2)
            .Push(&Foo::Method3);
    }

    void Method1() {}
    void Method2() {}
    void Method3() {}
};

int main(void)
{
    constexpr Node node = Foo::GetMethods();
}
```

The above code gives me the following error in main on the call to GetMethods():

```
const Node{MethodPtr{Foo::Method3, 0}, ((const Node*)(& Node{MethodPtr{Foo::Method2, 0}, ((const Node*)(& Node{MethodPtr{Foo::Method1, 0}, 0u}))}))}' is not a constant expression
```

Will someone please explain why this is not a constant expression? Or is there an alternate/correct way to achieve the goal of building a list of PTMFs at compile time?

EDIT: I am using the C++ compiler from avr-gcc 4.9.2. I will try this code on another compiler.

Comment: Useing g++ 5.3.1 I get `a.cpp:37:43: error: 'Node{MethodPtr{Foo::Method3, 0}, ((const Node*)(&<anonymous>))}' is not a constant expression`

Comment: The pointer is dangling, since all the temporaries created in `GetMethods` are destroyed at the `;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are storing addresses of non-static-storage-duration temporaries, which is not allowed in constant expressions. The current version of this rule is in [[expr.const]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5) (emphasis mine):

> A *constant expression* is either a glvalue core constant expression
>   whose value refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a
>   constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant
>   expression whose value is an object where, for that object and its
>   subobjects:
>
> - each non-static data member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression, and
> - **if the object or subobject is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past
>     the end of such an object ([expr.add]), the address of a function, or
>     a null pointer value**.

(C++11 contains similar rules (via the definition of *address constant expression*), but the constant expression rules were changed by multiple DRs before it was replaced by C++14 generalized `constexpr`, and I'm not really feeling like doing standard archaeology today.)

In fact, since every temporary `Node` created in `GetMethods()` except for the `Node` that got returned is destroyed at the `;`, the `Node` returned would contain a dangling pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the concise and correct answer! Is there another approach to achieve my goal here?

Comment: @Osuvaldo Why do you need a linked list anyway?

Comment: I don't exactly remember why I was doing this anymore and I'm not sure why I'm here now. However, I believe it may have had something to do with declaring a "statically dynamic sized array" of PTFM's to traverse. I'm pretty sure I wanted to use it for a series of tests that would be run on an embedded environment.

Comment: Hi T.C. Please, can you _add_ a real answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767506/19495502)?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the pointers to `Foo`'s methods, but `Foo` is a class, and you could call this in a derived class (where the methods are different).

Comment: I don't exactly understand your answer. Sure, a derived class that inherits publicly could hide the base methods. I understand and expect `GetMethods()` to return a linked list of methods of `Foo`.

Comment: @Osuvaldo if you want a list of the member functions for base classes, you'll have to build it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs in this area with gcc.  [See this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52892)

I've checking std::is_literal_type< Node >() in Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 and I get different answers. Clearly, regardless of the standard, this is still a dark corner of the language...

You have actually taken the address of a temporary and placed it into the list.  So, even if you could do this in a const Expr, the Node * points to an invalid object.  (You only have one Node object that survives the expression, but you have pointers to two more.)

However, you'll still have problems with a later version because your structure is not a [LiteralType](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType).

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a pointer to a temparary variable that goes out of scope.

Pointers to temporary objects are clearly not compile time constant values.  Dangling pointers doubly so.

Comment: "Pointers to temporary objects are clearly not compile time constant values." Nitpick: `static constexpr const int& i = 5; static constexpr const int* p= &i;  /* OK */`

Comment: @t.c. that "temporary" object is rather non-temporary.  ;)

Comment: @zenith inside the struct.  It contains pointers to other structs, all but the last one are temporary objects.  `Push` creates the pointer to the previous one, returning a new temporary.